# C# Как грамотно закрыть Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте, коллеги! Не думал, что будут проблемы с такими вот вещами, но тем не менее. Вот в чем суть проблемы. Разрабатываю программу, в которой из главной Form1, при нажатии на копку я открываю Form2.

```
   private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Далее уже на Form2 я выполняю код, который заполняет таблицу на Form1, при этом я вывожу данные в таблицу, а затем мне нужно закрыть Form2 сразу.

```
        Form1 f = new Form1();

        ////// Та та та здесь код запонения таблицы на Form1

        f.ShowDialog();
        Application.Exit();
```

Так вот в чем проблема: Form2 она то вроде закрывается, но по факту только скрывается. По долгу своей работы, мое приложение должно работать сутками в фоне и получается, что очередной раз пользователь открывает Form2, нажимает там на кнопку, таблица на Form1 заполняется, но Form2 не закрывается, а сворачивается... И так у меня плодятся окна Form1 и Form2 до бесконечности. Как можно это грамотно обыграть?
P.s. Пробовал и Form2.ActiveForm.Close() и this.Close() ничего не помогает. Может логическая ошибка где? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: подозреваю, вам нужно пересмотреть подход к решению проблемы. попробуйте один раз создавать формы, а потом скрывать/отображать. подробнее: https://victorz.ru/20160519140

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать, что код в обработчике события нажатия кнопки в `Form2` вида `this.Close()` не работает? И форма просто меняет свойство `Visible` на `false`? Полагаю, что вы смастерили семиколёсный велосипед в передаче данных между формами, отчего и страдаете. Получить доступ к форме, не важно к какой, можно так: `Form1 form1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];`, а дальше через делегаты обращайтесь к её методам и переменным как хотите. А через оператор `new` вы создаёте новый экземпляр объекта. Да и `Application.Exit();` - это вообще из другой оперы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример обработчика события по нажатию кнопки в **Form2** с изменением свойств объектов формы **Form1**.

```
private void buttonChangeDataForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = (Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"]; // Где Form1 это имя формы содежащаяся в переменной Name.
    if (form1 != null) // Если форма существует, то изменяем свойства её объектов
    {
        form1.textBox.Text = "Bla Bla BLa";

        ...


        this.Close(); // Закрываем текущую форму
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Error while changing data in Form1.", "Error"); // Выводим сообщение об ошибке изменения данных
}
```

Пример более правильного вызова/создания дочерней формы.

```
private void buttonCreateForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = (Form2) Application.OpenForms["Form2"]; // Где Form2 это имя формы содежащаяся в переменной Name.
    if (form2 == null) // Если форма не существует, то создаём
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2(); // Создание нового экземпляра формы
        form2.Show(); // Отображаем форму
    }
    else
        form2.Activate(); // Активируем форму на передний план (из трея или заднего плана)
}
```

Настоятельно рекомендую иметь ввиду контроль наличия (существования) окна, если вы используете окно без привязки к основному. Т.е. если дочерние окна можно убрать в фон или на задний план, то вы **обязательно** его потеряете.

Имена форм для `Application.OpenForms["AnyFormName"];` находятся в свойствах самих форм в переменной `Name`. Изменить (переопределять не стоит) можно в классе `*.Designer.cs`.

Если вам необходим доступ к методам формы, то необходимо создавать для них делегаты методов перед использованием.

P.S. Если предполагается использование дочернего окна ввод данных в которое обязателен для продолжения работы программы, то никогда не позволяйте это окно убирать в трей. Оно будет всегда поверх основного и его можно либо обработать вводом данных, либо закрыть. Так вы обезопасите себя от потери контроля над формами. И в этом случае вам нет необходимости контролировать наличие окна при его создании, т.к. доступ к основной форме будет ограничен. Достаточно будет выполнить код:

```
Form form2 = new form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Огромнейшее Вам спасибо! Действительно это и есть решение, я счастлив!

Answer (score 2):

После закрытия формы через `Close()` вызовите в первой форме у второй `Dispose()` и будет вам счастье. Иногда достаточно почитать официальные мануалы.

[MSDN Form.Close()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.form.close)

> Два условия, когда форма не удаляется при вызове Close это когда (1) это часть приложения многодокументного интерфейса (MDI) и форма не является видимой; и (2) **форма была отображена посредством ShowDialog**.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Form1FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel=Class1.fclose();
        }
        void Form1FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
public static bool fclose(){
            var result=MessageBox.Show("Вы действительно хотите закрыть программу?", "Подтверждение",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel,MessageBoxIcon.Question,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            if (result==DialogResult.OK)return false;
            else return true;
        }
```